# How to know if a function is from MFC or not

Tags: c++, mfc

I am maintaining a `Windows MFC application` and try to port the application to another-platform, but really frustrated at checking if the function or class is `MFC` or not.

For example, CFile is a MFC class from `MSDN` [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/60fh2b6f.aspx), but there is no document about `CString` is MFC or not.

It seems the functions or classes with the first upper alphabet 'C' are MFC, right?

There are MFC classes listed in the [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bk77x1wx.aspx)

Where can I find the MFC functions?

Thanks.

Comment: MFC uses an initial `C` for most classes, yes--but unfortunately, some others picked up on that, and did the same, so it's not necessarily a good indication of whether the class in question is part of MFC or not.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was no reference to CString on MSDN.

Comment: I find the reference  [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx) but am not sure if it is MFC class?

Comment: Look at this [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa251523%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). You will find the entire list of MFC classes for VS 6.0

Comment: If it is MFC class it will be derived from CObject except one or two

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to remove the MFC headers and see what breaks.

However, there are multiple `CString` implementations. IIRC, both MFC and ATL have one, and they can coexist. If you'd leave the ATL header in, you still wouldn't have a portable program.

Answer (score 0):

CString is from MFC. Of course, it depends what version of Visual Studio you are using. You can check on MSDN, first select the version of Visual Studio you are using. Then you should see all classes including CString. You can notice on the MSDN website that if you select the right Visual Studio [version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa251523%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) (VS 6.0 in this case) you will find the classes: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)